# Invalid Column Name Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Invalid column name when including a foreign key and referring to a second table.
I have already done this, but this time I can't find the error.

I added the model, the controller and the view the way I did with another view.
Is there something what I forgot maybe.  Last time I found the problem, but now it keeps giving the same error INVALID COLUMN NAME although I included the related table in my controller.

**Model**

```
public class Afspraken
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Afspraakid { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "titel")]
    [StringLength((40))]
    public String Afspraaktitel { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "details")]
    [StringLength((255))]
    public String Afspraakdetailomschrijving{ get; set; }

    public virtual Cities Locatieafspraak { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Locatieid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Datumafspraak { get; set; }

}

public class Cities
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 Cityid { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "postcode")]
    public String Postcode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "city")]
    public String City { get; set; }

    public virtual Countries Landen { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "country")]
    public Int32 Countryid { get; set; }

}

public class AfsprakenController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AfsprakenController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //return View(db.MyProfiles.ToList());

        var afspraken = _context.Afspraken.Include(e => e.Locatieafspraak).OrderBy(e => e.Datumafspraak).ToList();
        //Include(e=>e.TypeAfspraak).Include(e=>e.Locatieafspraak).
        return View(afspraken);

    }
```

**Index View**

```
@using CVtje.Models
@model IEnumerable<CVtje.Models.Afspraken>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index Afspraken";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("New", "New")
</p>*@
<table id="afspraken" class="table table-active table-hover">

        <tr>
            <th>
                Afspraaktitel
            </th>
            @*<th>
                Locatieid
            </th>*@
            <th>
                Locatieid
            </th>

        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Afspraaktitel
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Afspraakid
            </td>
            <td>


            </td>


  </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Didn't know you could include by FK. I'd use `_context.Afspraken.Include(e => e.Cities)...;`.

Comment: Where are you getting the error in controller or view? which line?

Comment: I already added  "Include(e => e.Locatieafspraak)"  This is a virtual reference (foreign key) to the Cities class, as you may see

Comment: the error in the line with the  "var afspraken":   var afspraken = _context.Afspraken.Include(e => e.Locatieafspraak).OrderBy(e => e.Datumafspraak).ToList();   It seems to give "var = null"  and an invalid column name.

Comment: SOLVEd: I renamed the column that are keys to  each other both the samen name: cityid  and then it works fine.  why is that.  Also the table needed to be renamed it must end with an 's'

Comment: What you see there are the code first conventions. The latter is called the Pluralizing Table Name convention and can be turned off, while the former is the naming convention for FK columns. If you want to use different table or column names, you'll have to define this mapping in the model builder.

Comment: I thought they didn't exist this time, because I built everything from scratch, last time I used Entity framework, but the sample on this page is built myself.

Comment: So if I would like to use to point twice to the same table, City and BirthCity, this would be not possible.  I would have to create two tables, beause of these conventions?

Comment: In the end I created two table with Cities, one for LivingPlace and one for BirthCity.  now it's fine.  Still, it would have been better to have one table.  But in one table twice a foreign key to the same table is not possible.